# How to resolve VS2019 warning to use `JoinableTaskFactory.SwitchToMainThreadAsync()` instead of Invoke / BeginInvoke?

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio

If I use

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { /*UI code here*/ }));
```

in a WPF project, Visual Studio 2019 gives me warning VSTHRD001:

> Await JoinableTaskFactory.SwitchToMainThreadAsync() to switch to the UI thread instead of APIs that can deadlock or require specifying a priority.

How do I implement this suggestion?

Comment: Did you google this at all?  The documentation seems to be a good place to start: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/managing-multiple-threads-in-managed-code?view=vs-2019

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute async code inside BeginInvoke?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58235729/how-to-execute-async-code-inside-begininvoke)

Comment: @ASh deleted that question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vs-threading/blob/master/doc/analyzers/VSTHRD001.md). You should replace the call to `BeginInvoke` with this:

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.ThreadHelper.JoinableTaskFactory.Run(async delegate {
    await ThreadHelper.JoinableTaskFactory.SwitchToMainThreadAsync();
    /*UI code here*/
});
```

Comment: ThreadHelper is from Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell namespace. Is the only way to install the extension SDK?

Comment: @geometrikal: Yes. Is that a question or an observation?

Comment: Is there a way to do it without that package?

Comment: @geometrikal: of course you need an actual implementation of `JoinableTaskFactory` to be able to use it.

Comment: I agree that it is not intuitive for something intended for general use to be in Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell instead of, say, System.Threading.Tasks. But this does seem to be the [recommended pattern](https://github.com/microsoft/vs-threading/issues/447#issuecomment-481481389).

Comment: What version of Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell is necessary? The highest possible for me (16.0.28729) does not have any ThreadHelper in its namespace.

Comment: I understand the benefit of switching using `await SwitchToMainThreadAsync()` over `Dispatcher.Invoke`, but how can `Dispatcher.InvokeAsync` cause deadlocks or "require specifying a priority"?

Comment: What library is this class in? Which nuget package should I download?